# C++ Read from file and assign to a variables

Tags: c++

i have a question.
I have a file in format like this:

```
A B
C D
E F
X Y
X2 Y2
X3 Y3
```

I know how to assign A,B,C,D,E,F,X,Y (each file i check have this data) but sometimes i have more data like X2 Y2, X3, Y3 and i want to assing these also (without previous knowledge about how many of these are in the file).

Actually my code looks like this:

```
reading >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f >> x >> y;
```

Could You help me? Thank You

Comment: just create a `std::vector` (or C-style array) to store the values, then use it in a loop like `while(reading >> values[k]){...; ++k; }`

Comment: If you don't know how many `X`s or `Y`s you're going to need, you will want to use a `vector` instead of an array.

Answer (score 5):

This solution with vectors might solve the problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void getItems(vector<string>& v, string path)
{
    ifstream is(path.c_str());
    istream_iterator<string> start(is), end;
    vector<string> items(start, end);
    v = items;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    getItems(v, "C:\test.txt");

    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: here i am assuming that your file is in C:\test.txt

Comment: You should use `move constructor` for `v`!

Comment: Code performance improvements are always possible. I am not so much acquainted with move constructor, more over it breaks with old compilers. So i want to keep it as it is.

Comment: Btw, @Quest, could you mention the change in a comment or answer, so i can learn it.

Comment: here you have [an example](http://ideone.com/vqHs1i)... you can just write: `v = std::move(items);`

Comment: Sorry that it takes that long. I had to do something first.

Comment: No problem. :) With copy constructor, you copy the whole array, while with move constr. you just copy a poiter to the first element and the actual size of array

Comment: but after the function execution, wont the code be destroyed. There seems to not be benefit of moving it in this example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68141/discussion-between-quest-and-ganesh-kamath).

Comment: I like this solution as it uses istream_iterator :) +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you want to be sure that *all* lines in the file must be read.

With the following code I solved the problem for me:

```
std::ifstream file_reading( filename_path_.c_str(), std::ios::in );
if( file_reading ) {

  std::string buffer;
  unsigned int line_counter = 0;

  while( std::getline( file_reading, buffer ) ) {

        std::istringstream istr;
        istr.str( buffer );

        if( buffer.empty() ) 
          break;

         istr >> x_array[local_counter] >> y_array[local_counter];

             line_counter++;
       }
}
```

using getline and a while loop you all get all lines in the file and store them in a std::vector which is resizable.
The instruction break will quit if no more data are found in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can input all of them as a string. Give the header as #input and use gets() function to input the entire input. Then work on the string. You can differentiate between the numbers by neglecting space(" ") and new lines ("\n"). 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you don't know how much data is in the file, it is worth to use a 
WHILE loop with the condition that you perform the while loop until it reaches the end of the file.

Something like this (ensure you include: iostream, fstream, and string):

```
int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream thefile ("test.txt");
    if (thefile.is_open()) 
    {
        while (thefile.good() )
        {
            getline (thefile, line);
        }
        thefile.close();
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Unable to open\n"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2D vector:

Input:

```
1 2 3
4 5
6
7 8 9
```

Code:

```
int  val;
string line;

ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

vector<vector<int> > LIST;

if (myfile.is_open())
{
   while ( getline(myfile,line) )
   {
      vector<int> v;

      istringstream IS(line);

      while( IS >> val)
      {
         v.push_back(val);
      }

      LIST.push_back(v);
   }

  myfile.close();
}

for(int i=0; i<LIST.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<LIST[i].size(); j++)
    {
        cout << LIST[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5
6
7 8 9
```

Comment: This will work only when all data have the same format

Comment: *Same type :D sorry. If the file contains `double` value or `string` you will get wrong result

Comment: Then there is no way to collect mixed type data if he does not know the structure..

Comment: he still can save em as strings

Comment: Then you have to convert to int/double by checking multiple conditions. I don't think this should be complicated. And OP didn't mention it. BTW, tnx